# G:each is not showing anything

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, grails-orm

Controller class

```
class EntidadController {
    def index(){
        def entidades = Entidad.list()
        [entidades:entidades]
        render(view:"index")
        for (x in entidades)
        {
            print(x.nombreEntidad)
        }
    }
}
```

Domain class

```
    class Entidad {

        String nombreEntidad
        int porcentaje
        static hasOne = [kiosko: Kiosko]
        static belongsTo = [adminCreador: Administrador,entidadSuperior: Entidad]
        static hasMany = [adminEntidad: Administrador, entidadesInferiores: Entidad]
        static constraints = {
            kiosko nullable:true        
            nombreEntidad nullable : false
            adminCreador nullable : true 
            adminEntidad nullable : true 
            entidadSuperior nullable : true 
            entidadesInferiores nullable : true
        }



}
```

View in gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>


</head>

<body>
<p>test</p>
<div controller="entidadController">
<g:each in="${entidades}"  var="x">
                <tr>
                        <td>${x.id}</td>

                </tr>
                </g:each>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think code is fine but i dont know why is not showing anything at the g:each tag, ive tried with a static array in gsp page and g each worked and i print at console and the array "entidades " had objects on it, its like my view cant read data from controller

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a render statement like this:

```
render(view:'index', model:[entidades: entidades])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need pagination and sorting in your view, you can do like this on your gsp

```
...
<body>
<p>test</p>
<div controller="entidadController">
<g:each in="${Entidad.list()}"  var="x">
            <tr>
                    <td>${x.id}</td>

            </tr>
            </g:each>
</div>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
def index(){
    ...
    [entidades:entidades]
    render(view:"index")
    ...
}
```

You are not sending `entidades` to the view. This can be corrected this way ([render docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html)):

```
def index(){
    ...
    render(view:"index", model:[entidades:entidades])
    ...
}
```

Also, if your view and your action share the same name, you don't need to use render method explicitly, but the map as the last line of the action (this is a grails convention). Like this:

```
def index(){
    ...
    [entidades:entidades]
}
```